# How to echo JSON array as Smart Table data with Angluarjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, smart-table

I'm pretty new to Angular, and trying to build a table using Smart Table based on data I'm fetching from a REST api. I can build the table fine with manually entered data, but when I try to insert a JSON array of data from the server the resulting table is empty.

Currently I have the following set up:
dataFactory.js - calls the API and gets a JSON response:

```
app.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

  var urlBase = 'http://myurl.com/api';
  var dataFactory = {};

  dataFactory.getOrders = function() {
    return $http.get(urlBase + '/orders');
  };

  return dataFactory;
}]);
```

My view is fairly basic and looks like this using to the Smart Table extension:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <table st-table="ordersTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th st-sort="createdBy">Name</th>
            <th st-sort="id">ID</th>
            <th st-sort="state">State</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in ordersTable">
            <td>{{row.createdBy}}</td>
            <td>{{row.id}}</td>
            <td>{{row.state}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And my MainController.js processes and stores the data, and builds the table:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', function($scope, dataFactory) {
  $scope.status;
  $scope.orders;
  getOrders();

  function getOrders() {
    dataFactory.getOrders()
      .success(function(ord) {
        $scope.orders = ord;
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        $scope.status = 'Unable to load order data: ' + error.message;
      });
  }

  $scope.ordersTable = [
    // If I build the data manually the table builds using the following 3 lines
    //{createdBy: 'Laurent', id: '56433', state: 'Open')},
    //{createdBy: 'Blandine', id: '34367', state: 'Open')},
    //{createdBy: 'Francoise', id: '34566', state: 'Closed'}
    //... however I actually want the data to come from the JSON array returned by my factory like this:

    $scope.orders
  ];
}]);
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get my data to show up in the table?

Comment: Did you check for http error ?

Comment: Yep - the data is definitely coming down OK - I have used it elsewhere. And there are no errors showing in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success callback you are updating $scope.orders and not $scope.orderTable. By the way use promise function then instead of success and error callback (extract from angularjs doc):

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Comment: And thanks for the depreciation heads up - got this from an old tutorial